# CTE table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssms, common-table-expression

I write this query

```
With TblCount(DName,TotEmp)
as
(
    select tblDepartment.DepartmentName,COUNT(\*)as TotalEmp
    from tblDepartment
    join tblEmp
        On tblDepartment.DeptId=tblEmp.Id
    Group by DepartmentName
)
```

and error is:-

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 10
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'select'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Completion time: 2022-03-22T19:45:50.7260303+05:30

as per syntax its correct then where the error is

Comment: Why do you have a backslash before `*`?

Comment: You need another `SELECT` statement *after* your CTE definitions also.

Comment: Is this the whole thing? The error message says lines 10 and 15, but you have only 9 lines.

Comment: `syntax its correct` no it's not. The query isn't complete and even if it was, it contains syntax errors, eg `COUNT(\*)`

Comment: In any case a CTE is *not* a table. It's a subquery, defined in such a way it can be used multiple times in the actual query, including places where a subquery can't be used. If you use the CTE only once you could easily replace it with a subquery, eg `select x.TotalEmp from (select tblDepartment.DepartmentName,COUNT(*)as TotalEmp ... ) x`

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is like below :

```
[ WITH <common_table_expression> [ ,...n ] ]  
  
<common_table_expression>::=  
    expression_name [ ( column_name [ ,...n ] ) ]  
    AS  
    ( CTE_query_definition )
```

You are using a non-Recursive CTEs where the CTE doesn’t use any recursion, or repeated processing in of a sub-routine.

As per the CTE Syntax each CTE query will start with a “With” followed by the CTE Expression name with column list.

In your case :

```
WITH tblcount(dname, totemp)
 AS (SELECT A.departmentname AS DName,
            Count(*)         AS TotalEmp
     FROM   tbldepartment AS A
            LEFT JOIN tblemp AS B
                   ON A.deptid = B.id
     GROUP  BY A.departmentname)
SELECT *
FROM   tblcount
```

Don't use implicit join the reasons why it is a bad idea to use this syntax are: It is possible to get accidental cross joins which then return incorrect results, especially if you have a lot of joins in the query.

Comment: And if this is all one is doing, whey put it in a CTE?

Comment: I am against that but if the OP didn't provide clear info I am trying to show him the syntax of the CTE